# IE 9 jQuery error: "Object doesn't support ... 'on'"?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I need help. I'm getting the following error in IE9. The code is working in FireFox:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'on'
```

This is raised on the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '#dropdownval select', function(event) {
        //logic function
    });
});
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: Which Jquery version you are using?

Comment: Have you tried `alert(typeof $(document).on);` before calling it? That will tell you if it exists or not.

Comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6.2

Comment: I am facing similar issue. I am using jQuery version 1.5.1. Any suggestions?

Comment: `$('#dropdownval select').live('change', ...)` worked for me (Putting comment here as an answer tom Q in previous comment.)

Answer (score 10):

#### Works in Firefox, not IE?

I would make sure that both browsers are loading the same source. To be honest, it's a bit impossible for Firefox to use `.on` while using jQuery 1.6, since the method didn't exist.

Within your console (F12 Developer Tools in IE and Firebug in Firefox) type the following:

```
jQuery.fn.jquery
```

This should resturn the current version of jQuery loaded on that particular page. For instance, as of today, running that command here on StackOverflow results in `"1.7.1"`. Secondly, to test for the presence of the `.on` method, you can access it without its parenthesis, using double-negation to cast it to a true boolean:

```
!!jQuery.fn.on // True if .on is present, False otherwise
```

#### With jQuery 1.6, use .delegate rather than .on

Since you're using jQuery 1.6, you don't have access to the [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, which was introduced in jQuery 1.7. The appropriate fallback would be to use the [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method instead, or you could upgrade to the latest version of jQuery ([Microsoft CDN](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_Releases_on_the_CDN_0), [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide), [jQuery CDN](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery)).

The syntax for [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) follows that of [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) pretty closely:

```
$("#dropdownval").delegate("select", "change", function(event){
    alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/rMBn4/

#### If you decide to upgrade...

You were close with your [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) code, but you don't want to bind the event as far down as the `document` object - this would mean the event would need to propagate a potentially long distance before being handled. Instead, as we did with the [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) example, we'll bind to something closer to the select element:

```
$("#dropdownval").on("change", "select", function(event){
    alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/rMBn4/1/

You'll note that the main difference between the two is the order of the first two parameters to the chained method. With [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), the selector precedes the event. With [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), the order is reversed.

Comment: Just a quick question, when you say to "type jQuery.fn.jquery" in the F12 dev tools in IE, are you talking about adding it as a Watch element, or is there somewhere in these tools that one can actually run immediate javascript?  I had been looking for this earlier and never found an option to do so.

Comment: @chrismay Good question, Chris. You can execute code in [IE 9's Console](http://i.imgur.com/pQEvx6h.gif).

Answer (score 7):

One of two things is happening:

1. `$` is not `jQuery`, but a function defined elsewhere; or,
2. `$` is not the correct version of jQuery. [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was introduced in 1.7.

---

For jQuery 1.6 the following `on`:

```
$(document).on('change', '#dropdownval select', ...)
```

can be written using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (since 1.4, deprecated 1.7):

```
$(document).delegate('#dropdownval select', 'change', ...)
```

can be written using [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (since 1.3, deprecated):

```
$('#dropdownval select').live('change', ...)
```

Please refer to the documentation for more options and caveats.

Using `delegate` *can* attach "below" the body (like `on`) where as `live` always attaches at the body level. Thus the above could possibly be written more efficiently, depending upon where the target is located.

Happy coding.

Comment: That's a mysterious you will never know.

Comment: @Jashwant Because things are fickle. Either the assertions I have made are true and I am correct or they are not true and I am incorrect. In any case, I have provided assertions to test/verify :-)

Comment: Following OP's update, you're right @pst. +1 for the case list.

Comment: @Jashwant, firefox does some modification to your code to remove small mismatches or something like that..

Comment: learnt a lesson :)
If its jQuery 1.6.2, `on` will be on on firefox but off on ie 9 :)

Comment: Sorry i was testing local machine In Server im using 1.6 , can not upgrade the jquery other functionality may break, please help

Comment: @pst (document).live ('change', '#dropdownval select', function(event) { is this correct

Comment: do this, `$('#dropdownval select').live('change',function(){});` . However, I would recommend switching to latest one. I dont think, it will break anything.

Comment: @user1433824 No. Please refer to the documentation.

Comment: Use delegate() instead of live(), if delegate() is available (like in your case), even if you think you need live(). There is a reason for which live() was deprecated in favor of delegate().

Comment: @pst: you are using deprecated function (live()). Change it into proper use of delegate().

Comment: `$('#dropdownval select').live('change', ...)` worked for me. I am using jQuery 1.5.1. I tried most of the possibilities mentioned above and finally this worked.