# How to validate a textbox value based on another textbox value inside gridview in jquery

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have two `textbox` inside `gridview`. If 1st text contains any data then 2nd `textbox` should not be empty. If 1st `textbox` is `null` then no validation for 2nd textbox. Only the alert will come after filling the 1st `textbox` 2nd textbox shouldn't empty. How to do that?

Any idea? Please help me out.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" Width="980px" ID="grdResUpdate" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
CssClass="TopMargin10 borderClass gridwrap" OnRowDataBound="grdResUpdate_RowDataBound" ShowHeader="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SO #" ItemStyle-Width="70px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Width="70px" ID="lblSOName" CssClass="gridwrap" Text='<%# Eval("SOName")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnFldSOId" Value='<%#Eval("SOId") %>' />
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test Type" ItemStyle-Width="300px" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="testTypeIdHdnFld" Value='<%#Eval("TestTypeId") %>' />
                <asp:Label runat="server" Width="150px" ID="lblTestTypeName" CssClass="gridwrap" Text='<%# Eval("TestTypeName")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test Case Count" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTestCaseCount" runat="server" HeaderText="Test Case Count" Width="80px" onkeydown="return isDigit(event)"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Environment" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEnvironment" runat="server" HeaderText="Environment" Width="80px" onkeydown="return isDigit(event)"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Passed" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassed" runat="server" HeaderText="Passed" Width="80px" onkeydown="return isDigit(event)"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Failed" ItemStyle-Width="70px" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFailed" runat="server" HeaderText="Failed" Width="80px" onkeydown="return isDigit(event)"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No Of Defects" ItemStyle-Width="70px" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDefects" runat="server" HeaderText="No Of Defects" Width="80px" onkeydown="return isDigit(event)"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hours" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtHours" runat="server" HeaderText="Hours" Width="80px" onkeydown="return isDigit(event)"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test Case Completed" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTCComp" runat="server" HeaderText="Test Case Completed" Width="80px" onkeydown="return isDigit(event)"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Percentage Completed" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPercComp" runat="server" HeaderText="Percentage Completed" Width="80px" onkeydown="return isDigit(event)"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerTop" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="rowbgblue" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="rowbginwhite" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I want when the user fills the `txtTestCaseCount` then he must have to fill `txtHours`

Comment: Please show us the generated html of at least on row of grid

Comment: Also show us the generated html

Answer (score 0):

First access gridview text boxes and then place checking code inside change event of `txtTestCaseCoun`t textbox

```
var textBoxOne = '#<%=grdResUpdate.ClientID%> input[id*="txtTestCaseCount"]';
var textBoxTwo = '#<%=grdResUpdate.ClientID%> input[id*="txtHours"]';

$(textBoxOne).on('change', function () {
  if($(textBoxTwo).val()==""){
     alert("Please fill hours textbox");
  }

});
```

this checks if `txtTestCaseCount` value is filled then if textbox `txtHours` is not filled then alert message is shown.

Comment: I am getting this error    JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'on'

Comment: which jquery version are you using .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892509/ie-9-jquery-error-object-doesnt-support-on

Comment: how to get textboxone value from gridview..is this write syntax?

Comment: yes it is.. what error message is shown ..have you gone through previous link posted.

Comment: Yes Object doesn't support property or method 'on'..this errors.Is there any other way?

Comment: i missed $ for textBoxTwo for making it as jquery object..that is why it was giving error since val() method was being called

Answer (score 0):

```
can check with onfoucsOut event

$("textbox2id").focusOut(function(){
if(!($("textbox2id").val() == ""))
{
alert("please enter a value as required");
$(this).focus();
}
})
```

Comment: but how to do accoring to textbox1?

Answer (score -1):

Every textbox in gridview has an id generated at runtime.
 Use that id as a selector, like

```
$("#textboxid").val()
```

.
This will give u the content of the textbox. Use it to validate the other textbox.
If suppose the id generated of txtTestCaseCount is like grdResUpdate_txtTestCaseCount then

```
      if($("#grdResUpdate_txtTestCaseCount").val().length < 0){//Code}
```

Comment: How ? can u give one example?