# Using $(this) for all input text types in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="text" id="txtOMSourceName" onkeypress="hideSpan()"/>
<input type="text" id="txtMPName" onkeypress="hideSpan()"/>
```

There are several textboxes on the page that I am validating and marking as error if no data is entered. I am adding error class to these text boxes. I want to remove the error class when they start typing in the textbox. I want to use this in jquery to refer to current textbox instead of ID, so I can reuse the code on other pages.

I am calling hideSpan on keypress of the text box. It works when i specify the ID. but not with this keyword

```
function hideSpan() {
 /*  $('#txtOMSourceName').removeClass('error');
     $('#ddlOMSite').removeClass('error');
     $('#txtMPName').removeClass('error');
     $('#txtOMResendInterval').removeClass('error');*/

    $(this).removeClass('error');
    $("#requiredspan").hide("slow");
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send `this` in the event to know who called the function:

```
<input type="text" id="txtOMSourceName" onkeypress="hideSpan(this)"/>
```

and the function:

```
function hideSpan(e) {
 /*  $('#txtOMSourceName').removeClass('error');
     $('#ddlOMSite').removeClass('error');
     $('#txtMPName').removeClass('error');
     $('#txtOMResendInterval').removeClass('error');*/

    $(e).removeClass('error');
    $("#requiredspan").hide("slow");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a nicer solution:

Let's say you have a bunch of text inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="txtOMSourceName" />
<input type="text" id="txtMPName "/>
```

Rather than code a function into each markup element you can just:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keydown', function() {

    $(this).removeClass('error');
    $('#requiredspan').hide('slow');
}
```

Comment: where do I put this function in JS file?

Comment: There are many places it could go, but the safest place since I don't know your script would be at the main level, inside the `$(window).ready( function() { --the code-- });`

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'on'  code:  function $(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#tTypes").tabs();
        $('#divAddOMSource').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, width: 500, resizable: false, title: "OM source" });
        $('#divAddEmailSource').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, width: 500, resizable: false, title: "Email source" });
    });

    

    $('input[type="text"]').on('keydown', function () {

        $(this).removeClass('error');
        $('#requiredspan').hide('slow');
    });
    
});

Comment: You had an extraneous function: paste this in: $(document).ready(function () { 

 $("#tTypes").tabs(); 
 
 $('#divAddOMSource').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, width: 500, resizable: false, title: "OM source" }); 

 $('#divAddEmailSource').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, width: 500, resizable: false, title: "Email source" }); 

 $('input[type="text"]').on('keydown', function () { $(this).removeClass('error'); $('#requiredspan').hide('slow'); }); 

});

Comment: I am still getting the error : JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'on' . This is a asp.net web form with html controls. I don't know if that is causing issue.

Comment: It sounds like you may be using an old version of jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892509/ie-9-jquery-error-object-doesnt-support-on